# Why is animation settings loaded in two separate object literals in TweenMax?

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I was just checking out [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/XJZWzR/), the code looks as follows:

```
var tmax_options = {
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true
};

var tmax_tl          = new TimelineMax(tmax_options),
    tween_options_to = {
      css: {
        transform: 'scale(0)',
        transformOrigin: 'center center'
      },
      ease: Cubic.easeInOut,
      force3D: true
    };

// Last Argument is Position Timing.
// Use this argument to stagger the visibility of surrounding circles
tmax_tl.to($('svg > circle:nth-of-type(1)'), 1, tween_options_to, 0)
       .to($('svg > circle:nth-of-type(2)'), 1, tween_options_to, 0)
       .to($('svg > circle:nth-of-type(3)'), 1, tween_options_to, 0)
       .to($('svg > circle:nth-of-type(4)'), 1, tween_options_to, 0)
       .to($('svg > circle:nth-of-type(5)'), 1, tween_options_to, 0)
       .to($('svg > circle:nth-of-type(6)'), 1, tween_options_to, 0)
       .to($('svg > circle:nth-of-type(7)'), 1, tween_options_to, 0)
```

I do understand most of the JS, but I just have a very general question of the unusual syntax - that is I see the options being loaded from 2 separate object literals, like so:

```
var tmax_options = {
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true
};
```

That's the first one and then:

```
  tween_options_to = {
      css: {
        transform: 'scale(0)',
        transformOrigin: 'center center'
      },
      ease: Cubic.easeInOut,
      force3D: true
    };
```

Now why are the animation setting being loaded separately? Couldn't they be loaded all in one object literal? I basically just wanted to know whether there is any compelling reason for the settings to be loaded in two separate object literals.

Comment: `tmax_options` variables are for **[TimelineMax](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/TimelineMax/)** instance and `tween_options_to` variables are for the third parameter for a **[`.to()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/to/)** call.

Comment: @TahirAhmed i can see that myself , i am asking WHY ?

Answer (score 1):

The GSAP `css:{}` object is optional. You can place all your properties in one object. The `css:{}` is just for convenience and adds a slight performance boost, since GSAP doesn't need to wrap your CSS properties for you. But again it is only optional and you don't have to use it anymore since GSAP version 1.18.0.

Also if you are using the `css:{}` object wrapper for your CSS properties. Then you should move `force3D: true` into your `css:{}` object since `force3D` is part of the [GSAP CSSPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/).

```
tween_options_to = {
  css: {
    transform: 'scale(0)',
    transformOrigin: 'center center',
    force3D: true
  },
  ease: Cubic.easeInOut
};
```

Or you could just have all in one object instead:

```
tween_options_to = {
  transform: 'scale(0)',
  transformOrigin: 'center center',
  force3D: true,
  ease: Cubic.easeInOut,
};
```

It could also be done like this using `scale` property. GSAP knows that `scale` is part of CSS `transform`

```
tween_options_to = {
  scale: 0,
  transformOrigin: 'center center',
  force3D: true,
  ease: Cubic.easeInOut,
};
```

GSAP equivalents for CSS transforms:

- **x** = translateX()
- **y** = translateY()
- **z** = translateZ()
- **rotation** = rotateZ() or rotate()
- **rotationX** = rotateX()
- **rotationY** = rotateY()
- **skewX** = skewX()
- **skewY** = skewY()

See the GSAP `CSSPlugin` Docs for more info:

http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/

Note about `css:{}` wrapper

> Originally, css-specific properties needed to be wrapped in their own object and passed in like TweenLite.to(element, 1, {css:{left:"100px", top:"50px"}}); so that the engine could determine the properties that should be funneled to CSSPlugin, but because animating DOM elements in the browser is so common, TweenLite and TweenMax (as of version 1.8.0) automatically check to see if the target is a DOM element and if so, it creates that css object for you and shifts any properties that aren't defined directly on the element or reserved (like onComplete, ease, delay, etc. or plugin keywords like scrollTo, easel, etc.) into that css object when the tween renders for the first time. In the code examples below, we'll use the more concise style that omits the css:{} object but be aware that either style is acceptable.

For example:

```
//as of 1.8.0 the following lines produce identical results:
TweenLite.to(element, 1, {top:"20px", backgroundColor:"#FF0000", ease:Power2.easeOut});
//longer, less convenient syntax:
TweenLite.to(element, 1, {css:{top:"20px", backgroundColor:"#FF0000"}, ease:Power2.easeOut});
```